# Django how to override form validation for a required field

Tags: python, django

I would like to override validation for a password field on my form which is required. Below is what I have tired.

```
 def clean(self):
        super(UserRegistrationForm, self).clean()

        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")

        if password:
            MIN_LENGTH = 6
            if len(password) < MIN_LENGTH:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Password must be at least %d characters long." % MIN_LENGTH)
        else:
            print(self._errors)
            del self._errors['password']


        return self.cleaned_data
```

However, I still get the message  `This field cannot be blank.`

PS my reasons for doing  this is if NONE my createUser method assigned a random password.

EDIT:

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)



        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        # turn off HTML5 validation
        self.helper.attrs = {'novalidate': ''}
        self.helper.form_show_labels =False

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            HTML('Enter Password'),
            Field('email'),
            Field('password', placeholder="Password", autocomplete='off'),
            Submit('submit', 'Login to your account', css_class='btn btn-primary btn-block'),
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mark the field as non-required in the form's constructor:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self,).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['password'].required = False
```

Comment: I'm using crispy forms so that seems to give me a KeyError: 'password'

Comment: what does `print self.fields.keys()` say?

Comment: = ['email', 'password']

Comment: that doesnt make any sense

Comment: updated OP to show you. if I add self.fields['password'].required = False I get the key error

Comment: sorry yedpodtrzitko my bad. the error was from leaving in the del self._errors['password'] after I added your code! You code works.